# WSL2 Azure SQL Connection Issue

Tags: .net, azure-sql-database, wsl-2

I am running a .NET 6 web app on WSL2 (Windows Sub-system for Linux), but having connection issue with Azure SQL connection. I keep getting the following exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The exception handler configured on ExceptionHandlerOptions produced a 404 status response. This InvalidOperationException containing the original exception was thrown since this is often due to a misconfigured ExceptionHandlingPath. If the exception handler is expected to return 404 status responses then set AllowStatusCode404Response to true.
---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
```

I am using the connection string in the following format.

```
Server=tcp:[ServerName].database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=[DatabaseName];Persist Security Info=False;User ID=[UserName];Password=[Password];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

This works on Windows, but it does not work on WSL2. I checked with tcpping and nslookup that the database server and port is reachable, but the app cannot connect to it for some reason.

Does anyone know why this is happening and is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using [ExceptionHandlerOptions.AllowStatusCode404Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.exceptionhandleroptions.allowstatuscode404response)  property.
   Modify the `UseExceptionHandler` method as follows:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
    app.UseExceptionHandler(
          new ExceptionHandlerOptions()
          {
              AllowStatusCode404Response = true, // important!
              ExceptionHandlingPath = "/error"                  
          }
      );      
  }
```

- Also, if Windows has any VPN software, turn it off because it can interfere with WSL2 Windows network connectivity.